# Unable to read body in post response [express.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I am making a post request using Restlet client tool in chrome. In console.log(res), I can clearly see that there is body present there with totally correct data but still I am always getting an error message saying body is undefined when doing res.body.

Here is the code

```
var express = require('express');
var parser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(parser.json());

var db = mongoose.connection;

var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

var router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Something is happening.');
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});

router.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.json({msg: 'Welcome to Pre-Health API!'});
}); 

var User = mongoose.Schema({
        first_name: String,
        last_name: String
    },{
        collection: 'User',
        timestamps: true
    });

router.route('/user').post(function(res,req) {
    var user = mongoose.model('user',User);
    console.log(req);
    var new_user = new user({
       first_name: req.body.first_name,
       last_name: req.body.last_name
    });

    user.save(function(err) {
        if(err) res.send(err);
        res.json({message: "User created"});
    });
});

app.use('/api',router);

app.listen(port);
console.log('API Listening on port: ' + port);
```

Comment: can you share the console.log(res) result?

Comment: sure I will share it.

Comment: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=0f2b9c9af8e986e983049874f4863f4a @JunbangHuang

Comment: `res` doesn't have a `body` property.

Comment: It does, look at line 533 @luisenrike

Comment: No, that one is from the underline request, `res.req.body`, that is the same of saying `req.body`

Comment: So, what do you suggest I should do to get that data? @luisenrike

Comment: In what part? I don't see any problem with your code. You are using `req.body` already (`req.body.first_name`, `console.log(req)`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142230/discussion-between-mohit-bhatia-and-luisenrike).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function you have `req` and `res` inverted, it should be:

```
router.route('/user').post(function(req, res) { ...
```